# Subset columns based on set of randomly generated numbers in R

Tags: r, random, indexing

I want to generate a set of 1000 random numbers between 1 and 20000 to then use those to subset a dataframe.

```
sample.int(20000, 2000, replace = TRUE)
```

Then I want to copy/paste these numbers into this vector

```
df_sub <- df[,c(65,25,1,6000,1056, ...)]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No need to copy. just store them in a variable. ie `var <- sample(20000, 1000, TRUE)` then use the var to subset

Comment: No need to copy/paste, just sample directly in the indexing operation. For example, to randomly select 1000 rows between 1 and 20000 (with replacement): `df[sample(1:20000, 1000, replace=T),]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to copy/paste, just sample directly in the indexing operation:

For example, to randomly select 1000 rows between 1 and 20000 (with replacement):

```
df[sample(1:20000, 1000, replace=T),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use dplyr's row_number() function to get the row id and sample the rows

```
   df %>%
      mutate(row_id=row_number()) %>% 
      slice_sample(n=1000)
```

To get the row ids

```
   df %>%
      mutate(row_id=row_number()) %>% 
      slice_sample(n=1000) %>%
      pull(row_id)
```

Comment: `row_id` is doing nothing in the first chunk of code other than add a column to the `data.frame` that contains the row number. The sampling is completely independent of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use clipr to write the vector to your clipboard.

```
library(dplyr)
s <- sample.int(20000, 2000, replace = TRUE)
vectorToCopy <- s %>%
  stringr::str_c(",", collapse=" ") %>% # sep each element by comma
  stringr::str_sub(., 1, nchar(.)-1) %>% # remove last comma
  str_c("c(", ., ")") # add parentheses
clipr::write_clip(vectorToCopy) # write to clipboard
```